# store image in database and retrieve in datagridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying out new things myself in .net.I want to store image url in database and retrieve it dynamically in gridview.I have tried using blob.But i do not want to store image in database but just the urls.Some solutions that i have found that we can use template field in gridview and somehow use bind function.Also I can store all images in project folder and retrieve the images from folder.On button click i want to display images in gridview.But still i am not able to proceed forward.This is my code so far....

```
<div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="Model_Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Model_Id" HeaderText="Model_Id" 
                    InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Model_Id" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Model_Name" HeaderText="Model_Name" 
                    SortExpression="Model_Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Max_seats" HeaderText="Max_seats" 
                    SortExpression="Max_seats" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Image" HeaderText="Image" SortExpression="Image" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Model]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
```

Comment: try this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/268123/Display-Store-and-Retrieve-Image-Data-from-Databas

Answer (score 0):

inside your `GridView` add a template field i.e.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="Model_Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Photo">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <img src='<%# Eval("Image") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>  
            //other bound columns
   </Columns>            
</asp:GridView>
```

where `Image` is the column inside your table `[Model]`, containing Image URL.
if Images don't show, check the relative url structure, you might need to prefix/adjust it like this:

`/images/image1.jpg` to `../images/image1.jpg`  (depends on relative location of your folder containing images)

it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

store the images in a folder in solution explorer of your project, if you want to save the link to the database then set the data type of the coloumn to varchar(MAX) and store the link of the image to database table like below.

1.If your folder name is Image, then store the url as ../Image/picture.jpg

2.go to quick task menu of the gridview and click edit fields and from the AVAILABLE FIELDS list choose "ImageField" and click add, the image field is then added to SELECTED FIELDS

3.move the "ImageField" in SELECTED FIELDS up or down to place it between other columns

4.Click the "ImageField" and ImageField properties will be displayed on the right side, GOTO
  DATA and in "DataImageUrlField" select the Database table column name from where you want to retrieve the image .

Thats Should Work, ImageField will automatically generate the HTML code for your images to be displayed.